# iOS handling Push notification tap when app is active

Tags: ios, push-notification, onesignal

How can I handle push notification tap when app is active?
`didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]` is called when iOS device receives a push notification and same function is called when user taps on the notification. How can I differentiate in this function how this function is called? I'm using `OneSignal` of push notification in case it's necessary to understand the problem.

Comment: save flag when your app willResignActive, check it in didReceiveRemoteNotification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OneSingal` has closures which informs you about notifications and user actions. This is how I use that

```
func initOneSignalNotifications(withLaunchOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) {
        let onesignalInitSettings = [kOSSettingsKeyAutoPrompt: false]

        OneSignal.initWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions, appId: Constants.oneSignalKey, handleNotificationReceived: { (receivedNotification) in

            //Notification is received

        }, handleNotificationAction: { (notificationResult) in
            //Notification was tapped
        }, settings: onesignalInitSettings)

        OneSignal.inFocusDisplayType = OSNotificationDisplayType.notification;
        OneSignal.promptForPushNotifications(userResponse: { accepted in
            FileHandler.log(message: "Notification permission granted: \(accepted)", tag: .application, logLevel: .info)
        })
    }
```

Here `inFocusDisplayType` means when your app is open, `OneSignal` will still display a notification.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle click in, If your target is above iOS 10.

```
func userNotificationCenter ( _ center : UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive
response : UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler :
@escaping () -> Void ) {
        // perform notification received/click action as per third party SDK as per their document
    }
}
```

else, You need to manage it with flags in `didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]`.